# Simple delete row date from database

Tags: php, sql, database, delete-row, sql-delete

I want to delete this row from datebase without redirect and forms..
Any .. I do not want to use java .. I want to work only.. I will refresh page manually

its true or not ?

```
function delete() {
   mysql_query("SELECT * FROM wtable");
   mysql_query("DELETE FROM `s2010_wdb`.`wtable` WHERE `id`='".$poste['id']."'");
}
```

---

```
<form>
<h1>POST TITLE</h1><input type="submit" name="delete" value="title"></a>
</form>
```

Comment: I think you will need AJAX for that. And also you have several typos in your code.

Comment: No, that will not work.  Not sure where to being with explaining why though.  It seems you have a fundamental misunderstanding of the difference between server side (PHP) and client side (Javascript) code works.

Comment: in fact, you HAVE to write a code that deletes a row using form. Because you will need that code anyway. So, you'd better start writing already.

Comment: Any .. I do not want to use javascript .. I want code to work only

Comment: What do you think `onclick` is? That's a JavaScript event.

Comment: oh.. ok.. what is true ? input ?

Comment: Too bad this code is nonsense. You can't delete a row without form or JS. Try to think better and ask another question, more sensible one

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not clear about your question but if you want to delete something from database after click the submit button then you can write code in the following way.

```
<form action="submitURL.php" method="get">
    <input type="hidden" name="inputid" value="id1" />
    <input type="hidden" name="actionname" value="delete" />
    <input type="submit" name="delete" value="title">
</form>
```

submitURL.php will be like:

```
<?php 
    if($_GET["actionname"]=="delete"){
        mysql_query("DELETE FROM `s2010_wdb`.`wtable` WHERE `id`='".$poste['id']."'");
    }
?>
```

if you want to stay in the same page where you are just put the same file name in "action" or you can use [PHP_SELF](http://www.html-form-guide.com/php.../php-form-action-self.html)

Comment: thank you i will test it.. but now i busy for Egypt Celebrations

Answer (score 2):

You can't run PHP code in a web browser, so to do this without a form or a redirect, you must use AJAX to make an HTTP request to the server, where the delete will occur.